# How do you usually take notes for reading source code of a big software

Tags: knowledge-management

For big software, take notes is useful for understanding the big picture.

How you take notes? With pen/paper, or just a notepad; and what you usually will write for note?

Comment: Is this really a serious question? I use crayons and paper with really fat lines. And when i'm not using that i will use object models, class diagrams, sequence diagrams, etc.

Comment: Just for curiosity, sometimes it took me a long time to catch the software's design/implementation.  Especially when there is not much documents about the design or implementation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're a team: install a wiki and contribute all your discoveries there. Will preserve the knowledge for eternity and sharing it will be very easy.

Answer (score 1):

I generally note down the Important methods. Also mark important logic part part in IDE.